# Programming dynamic panels in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

My programming experience is short and I have written several applications but am very much still a novice in VB.NET.

I am writing an application which requires information to be displayed in panels. These panels need to be created at runtime based upon the information from a database. The database contains the information and I will create the panels and put the data into it. The data will be dynamic labels which will update with information to the user.

My problem is that I've never really created dynamic controls before and I seem to be having problems. If I select one item in the database to be created then it works fine. More than one is where I'm having the issue. It goes through the code and adds the controls to the form but only actually displays the last panel it created. The space on the form where the other panels should be is blank.

Also, I want to refer to the dynamically created panels after they are created. I am giving them each a unique name as they are created. Obviously I can't refer to their name directly in the IDE, Is there another way of referencing the name I am giving them?

My code is below, if anyone can point me in the right direction as to what I'm missing and doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

```
 Dim cmd03 As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Nothing, strConnection)
    Dim strMachineID As String = String.Empty
    Dim strMachineIP As String = String.Empty
    Dim strMTB As String = String.Empty

    Dim MachinePanel As New Panel
    Dim MachineName As New Label
    Dim MachineStatus As New Label
    Dim RunningProg As New Label
    Dim RunningPart As New Label
    Dim PartsComplete As New Label
    Dim startpointX As Integer = 12
    Dim startpointY As Integer = 82



    Try
        cmd03.CommandText = "Select * FROM tblMachines WHERE tblMachines.Monitor = TRUE"

        strConnection.Open()

        Dim myreader02 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd03.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        While myreader02.Read
            strMachineID = myreader02.GetValue(0)
            strMachineIP = myreader02.GetValue(10)
            strMTB = myreader02.GetValue(1)

            MachinePanel.Name = "pnl" & strMTB & strMachineID
            MachinePanel.Size = New Point(918, 120)
            MachinePanel.Location = New Point(startpointX, startpointY)
            MachinePanel.BackColor = Color.White
            'MachinePanel.Visible = True
            'MachinePanel.Enabled = True

            MachineName.Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID
            MachineName.Text = strMTB & Chr(32) & strMachineID
            MachineName.Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 26, FontStyle.Bold)

            MachineName.Location = New Point(4, 34)

            MachineName.AutoSize = True

            MachineStatus.Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "status"
            MachineStatus.Text = "?Unknown?"
            MachineStatus.Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 22.2, FontStyle.Bold)
            MachineStatus.Location = New Point(380, 34)
            MachineStatus.AutoSize = True

            MachineStatus.Enabled = True
            MachineStatus.Visible = True

            RunningProg.Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "prog"
            RunningProg.Text = "prog????"
            RunningProg.Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
            RunningProg.Location = New Point(760, 9)
            RunningProg.AutoSize = True



            RunningPart.Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "part"
            RunningPart.Text = "part????"
            RunningPart.Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)

            RunningPart.Location = New Point(760, 44)
            RunningPart.AutoSize = True


            PartsComplete.Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "complete"
            PartsComplete.Text = "complete????"
            PartsComplete.Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
            PartsComplete.Parent = MachinePanel
            PartsComplete.Location = New Point(760, 78)
            PartsComplete.AutoSize = True
            ' PartsComplete.Enabled = True
            'PartsComplete.Visible = True

            Me.Controls.Add(MachinePanel)
            MachinePanel.Controls.Add(MachineName)
            MachinePanel.Controls.Add(MachineStatus)
            MachinePanel.Controls.Add(RunningProg)
            MachinePanel.Controls.Add(RunningPart)
            MachinePanel.Controls.Add(PartsComplete)
            MachinePanel.Visible = True
            MachinePanel.Enabled = True
            MachinePanel.Show()


            startpointY = startpointY + 140
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        strConnection.Close()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You have to move the code `Dim MachinePanel As New Panel`, etc, into your loop.  Right now, you only create the control once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn [option strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) on as `MachinePanel.Size = New Point(918, 120)` accepts a `Size` structure and not a `Point` structure. Secondly you'll need to create a new instance of each object in each cycle.

```
While myreader02.Read

    MachinePanel = New Panel() '
    MachineName = New Label()
    MachineStatus = New Label()
    RunningProg = New Label()
    RunningPart = New Label()
    PartsComplete = New Label()

    With MachinePanel
        .Name = "pnl" & strMTB & strMachineID
        .Size = New Size(918, 150)
        .Location = New Point(startpointX, startpointY)
        .BackColor = Color.White
    End With

    With MachineName
        .Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID
        .Text = strMTB & Chr(32) & strMachineID
        .Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 26, FontStyle.Bold)
        .Location = New Point(0, 0) '<- In relation to MachinePanel.ClientRectangle
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    With MachineStatus
        .Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "status"
        .Text = "?Unknown?"
        .Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 22.2, FontStyle.Bold)
        .Location = New Point(0, 30)
        .AutoSize = True
        .Enabled = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    With RunningProg
        .Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "prog"
        .Text = "prog????"
        .Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        .Location = New Point(0, 60)
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    With RunningPart
        .Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "part"
        .Text = "part????"
        .Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        .Location = New Point(0, 90)
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    With PartsComplete
        .Name = "lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID & "complete"
        .Text = "complete????"
        .Font = New Font("Bookman Old Style", 12, FontStyle.Bold)
        .Parent = MachinePanel
        .Location = New Point(0, 120)
        .AutoSize = True
    End With

    MachinePanel.Controls.AddRange(New Control() {MachineName, MachineStatus, RunningProg, RunningPart, PartsComplete})
    Me.Controls.Add(MachinePanel)
    startpointY = startpointY + 150

End While
```

Comment: @davidsbro Thanks! I <3 option strict ON! ;D

Comment: Thanks @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå that worked great. Any pointers on the other part of my question?

Comment: "Also, I want to refer to the dynamically created panels after they are created. I am giving them each a unique name as they are created. Obviously I can't refer to their name directly in the IDE, Is there another way of referencing the name I am giving them?"

Comment: Refer to a _MachinePanel_ panel by doing `Dim machinePanel As Panel = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Item("pnl" & strMTB & strMachineID), Panel)`. Now, if you want to refer to a _MachineName_ label inside the _MachinePanel_ panel you do `DirectCast(machinePanel.Controls.Item("lbl" & strMTB & strMachineID), Label)`.